# AngularJs calling service function from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got some app in AngularJs, and I've encountered a problem. I need to call a function from service in controller.

my service:

```
var DataService = ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'alert', function ($http, $q, $window, alert) {
    function print () {
        console.log('smth');
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
var Controller = function ($scope, $state, OffersService, commonFunction, dataService, alert, blockUI) {
    function printSmth () {
        dataService.print();
    }
}
```

function printSmth is called from ng-init in html, and I get exception saying that dataService.print is not a function.

Does anybody know the proper way to do it? I can't change it to .service it must be done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below..

```
var DataService = ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'alert', function ($http, $q, $window, alert) {
   this.print = function () {
        console.log('smth');
    };
}
```

or

```
var DataService = ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'alert', function ($http, $q, $window, alert) {
       function print() {
            console.log('smth');
        };
       return {
        print: print
       };
}
```

Comment: Welcome @egzaell

Answer (score 1):

The best way to what you want to accomplish would be something like:

Service:

```
/* recommended */

// dataservice factory
angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

dataservice.$inject = ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'alert'];

function dataservice($http, $q, $window, alert) {
    return {
        print : print 
    };

    function print () {
        console.log('smth');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
/* recommended */

// controller calling the dataservice factory
angular
    .module('app.avengers')
    .controller('YourController', YourController);

YourController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'OffersService', 'commonFunction', 'dataservice', 'alert', 'blockUI'];

function YourController($scope, $state, OffersService, commonFunction, dataservice, alert, blockUI) {
    $scope.printSmth = function printSmth() {
           dataService.print();
    };
}
```

I recommend you start reading some [`style guides for AngularJS`](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#data-services). You will make your life and your development team more productive in the future.

Comment: It is a good example written using some good practices. Please refer this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Controller = function ($scope, $state, OffersService, commonFunction, dataService, alert, blockUI) {
```

Change `dataService` to `DataService`

----------------UPDATE--------------------

The function you have defined in controller cannot be accessed in view unless its a `$scope` function.

So make the print function in your controller to be

```
$scope.printSmth = function () {
    dataService.print();
}
```

Comment: nope, I'm getting the same exception, and about that kind of thinking in that controller I have working access to vars in dataService

Comment: Have a look @egzaell